# Android studio orange gradle file

Tags: java, android, gradle

Hi all after a recent commit I noticed two extra folders being generated in my project directory that I have never seen before [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y69qv.png) I dont know if I should ignore it or be worried, anyone have any idea? It is an orange gradle file and an orange build file

Answer (score 0):

The `build` directory contains e.g. build outputs and intermediate files. The `.gradle` directory contains e.g. cached versions of your project's dependencies.

These are generated and updated at build time and are nothing to worry about. You should not include them in version control either.

Comment: I think I have included them in version control should I remove them @Iaalto

Comment: They are in the Android Studio default .gitignore but if you have them in version control, it's better that you remove them there. No need to track generated files.